# shiny.fluent or shiny.blueprint with bslib in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, bslib

I am developing an application in R with the `bslib` library, I want to incorporate components (inputs) from `shiny.fluent` or `shiny.blueprint`.

I tried adding `shiny.blueprint` `multistepDialog`, however I am not getting the expected results. I also tried to incorporate `shiny.fluente` panel, but I'm not getting what I want either.